# How do i compress a PDF in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pdf, dart, compression

I built an app for my university where students can access documents such as notes, question papers etc. in PDF format.

I am using Firebase Storage for the back-end. I want to compress the PDF files client side. I thought of using ilovepdf.com's API but i'm not able to do that. Is there anyway to do that in dart? any package in flutter?

Would be great if someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any file compression method, not just those specific to PDF. You could use the [archive package](https://pub.dev/packages/archive), which has multiple compression options.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar to the question here, checkout the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66624821/11533306