# How to compress the pdf document before uploading to firebase storage and database in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, compression

In my flutter project  I  (users) have to Upload number of pdfs. So  to use the firebase conservatively I need to compress the images and pdfs  while uploading to the firebase storage.

Note: I am using  firebase spark plan ( free upto 5GB only)

Please suggest me a techinique for compressing pdf documents as I am using file_picker for picking pdfs documents and then firebasestorage to upload.

Frankly speaking I have searched pub.dev , but did'nt find any.

Comment: Try way from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759571/how-do-i-compress-a-pdf-in-flutter) question.

Comment: No it doesn't support pdf compression and no code for fluttter in it.

Comment: It can create a zip archive and you can store your PDF in it.

Comment: Ok You are right I can  store pdf in zip file and upload to firebase. But again I ( users) have to extract the zip file and view the pdf everytime.  So please suggest me another technique which can compress pdf directly, and then I can upload to firebase storage.

Comment: Please try to give any other alternative or solution to compress the pdf document  in flutter.

Comment: I want to compress the pdf  document before uploading firebase storage. Please let me know How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, i have created a flutter package. For now it works only for android device, and compression quality is pretty good. you can check it out here https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_compressor

Comment: Are you implementing it for iOS as well?

Comment: I was thinking about this, because the android side code is written natively in java, i want to do the same for iOS but i don't have any apple device or XCode to write iOS specific code, so I'm looking for someone who can write and test IOS side of the plugin.